# CSS marginless printing of multiple pages. Where is this tiny additional height coming from?

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries

[Live Demo](https://codepen.io/KerimG/pen/WNgoNMN), sorry for the messy CSS, I've been trying out a bunch of things.

I am trying to "print" PDF files using the browser print dialog. Each file contains 4 pages in the DIN lang format plus 3mm on each side.

In the HTML below, each `.page` represents a physical page with dimensions as defined above. The printable area is the exact DIN lang dimensions (105mm x 210mm) centered on the page.

For some reason, no matter what I try, I cannot get the `.page` element to fit exactly into what's defined in `@page`, there's a tiny bit of additional height that becomes more pronounced as I add pages. Adding `page-break-after: always;` reveals however, that the first page is already a bit too tall (as there is a seemingly blank page following it).

[image]

Comment: @KJ this is interesting but I am not really sur ehow to interpret this. Where is ths 209.8mm coming from?

Comment: @KJ I figured that part, but where in the code snippet that you inserted do you see the `209.888` value? I kind of suspected that the there's a slight rounding error or issue with the PDF generator but couldn't figure out where. 
Also, I think it needs to be something like `.page { height: 215.9mm; }` to account for 3mm margin on each side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing multiple configurations and searching for hours on SO and on other websites, I found a solution, ***not the perfect one I admit***, but the best available right now.

In your print media query, just put the following:

```css
@media print {
  body {
     border: 1px solid transparent;
  }
}
```

### Complete code to run:

```js
window.print();
```

```css
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements, but allowing components to change */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: fit-content;
}

.print-area {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 105mm;
  height: 210mm;
  font-size: 12pt;
  display: none;
}

.page {
  display: block;
  height: 216mm;
  width: 111mm;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
  /* page-break-after: always; */
}

#page-one {
  background-color: rgb(206, 135, 208);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#page-two {
  background-color: rgb(78, 73, 212);
}
#page-three {
  background-color: rgb(232, 227, 151);
}
#page-four {
  background-color: rgb(118, 196, 124);
}

@media print {
  body {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
  }
}

@page {
  size: 111mm 216mm;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="page" id="page-one">
  <div class="print-area">
    <h1>Hello from page 1</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="page" id="page-two">
  <div class="print-area">
    <h1>Hello from page 2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="page" id="page-three">
  <div class="print-area">
    <h1>Hello from page 3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="page" id="page-four">
  <div class="print-area">
    <h1>Hello from page 4</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Undoubtedly this is a weird solution. However, this ensures that the (final) green slide won't overflow and thus you won't have a blank page at the end.

Comment: Wow, this actually works but it's such a weird solution! Do you have an idea what might be causing this problem? Did you find anything that you could share? I was able to simplify the CSS a bit more and in the end it really seems to depend on the `border: 1px solid transparent;` rule for the body.

Comment: I will accept your answer, so I don't forget to do it before the bounty time runs out. But I'd really appreciate it, if you posted some additional information on how your found this. And maybe an explanation, if you have one.